# fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin giving errors about @types and Mocha

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-4, ts-loader

I'm using [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/) and [fork-fs-checker-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Realytics/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin) in a project, and it's complaining about `node_modules/@types`, for example:

```
ERROR in D:/temp/temp-vscode/temp-electron/application-volume-    change/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
ERROR in D:/temp/temp-vscode/temp-electron/application-volume-change/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2288,19):
TS2320: Interface 'Element' cannot simultaneously extend types 'ReactElement<any>' and 'ReactElement<any>'.
  Named property 'type' of types 'ReactElement<any>' and 'ReactElement<any>' are not identical.
```

And also about `it`, `describe`, `expect`, etc. with errors such as:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
```

I have tried to exclude the directories in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "node_modules/@types"
]
```

And (part of) my `webpack.config`:

```
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
...
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
          happyPackMode: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
]
...
plugins: [
  new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()
]
```

Versions:

```
"webpack": "^4.16.0"
"ts-loader": "^4.4.2"
"fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.3"
```

Comment: Having a similar problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I don't think so! The question is more than a one year old, and, honestly, I don't remember the context I asked this question for :(